# Vertically aligning two FontAwesome icons

Tags: font-awesome, vertical-alignment, font-awesome-5

I have some simple code which includes two font icons from FontAwesome.

They render like this in my browser:

[image: Side by side example of two icons]

Note that although both elements are 16px in height, the two icons are not vertically aligned, the calendar rests lower down than the

[image: Screenshot showing gap]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>
  <i class="fad fa-times-hexagon text-danger fa-fw"></i>
  <i class="fad fa-fw fa-calendar"></i>
</p>
```

I can "fix" with `bottom: -1px;` on the hexagon but is there a better way to get the baselines aligned?

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a problem with the glyphs defined in the font itself

[image: calendar secondary glyph]

[image: hexagon secondary glyph]

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11477